# Generate a new id for row in database?

Tags: php, ajax, database

I am using jQuery draggable, when the draggable element moves I save those css values (left, top) into the database ($wpdb) using ajax... I have no problem when there is one draggable element it runs smooth... but adding onto the project I want to add multiple draggable elements and thats where I am having a problem... here is the code I am sending the data to the database...

```
    global $wpdb;


    //The data here comes from an ajax call
    $_POST['x'];
    $_POST['y'];
    $_POST['id']; 

    $term_id = 100; 
    $name = $_POST['id']; 
    $slug = $_POST['x'];
    $term_group = $_POST['y']; 

    if(isset($_POST['id'],$_POST['y'], $_POST['x'])){
        print_r($_POST);
    }

    //Im adding into wp_terms a default table (for testing)... 
    $query = "INSERT INTO $wpdb->terms (term_id, name, slug, term_group) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)"; 

    //Here I insert the ajax data into the columns 
    $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare($query, $term_id, $name, $slug, $term_group));

    $wpdb->update("$wpdb->terms", array('slug' => $_POST['x'], 'term_group' => $_POST['y']), array('name' => $_POST['id']));


    die();
```

This code summed up: It connects to the $wpdb then I take the data from the ajax call and store them in a variable.. I am targeting the wp_terms table... So on draggable element `stop` the ajax data is sent to my script and stored in the database, on `update` every time draggable stops I preserve that row and only update the `x` and `y` values located in `slug` && `term_group` that has the `name` of `$_POST['id']`... this updates it well, but since `$term_id = 100` a static value, I cannot create a new row for an element with a new `$_POST['id']`.. does that make sense.. its much more simple than I think I made it out to be... I am trying to do what I am already doing but when there is a new `$_POST['id']` I need to generate a `$term_id = 101` dynamically it works exactally how I want if I manually give the row a term_id of 101...

Table looks like this...

[image: table]

Im trying to add a 101 and silly2.. then 102 silly3.. something like that, then when the last two values x & y change the 152 & 32 changes but term_id 101 stays and silly 2 stays...

[image]

The thing here is I dont want to create a new instance of silly, silly2, silly3... I want to overwrite the last two columns..

Comment: Can you print your final query with values substituted and try to paste it in phpmyadmin and see what error it gives. Also can you throw some light on your table structure.

Comment: Added an image of the table.... when a new draggable element is created, it will get an id of silly2... that id is passed through akax and sent to the name column... it needs a new term_id.. but once it get a new term_id I want it to stick.. I can generate a random ID but that is not good for me

Answer (score 0):

Try using [auto increment](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp) in sql table definition. If you cant modify the table definition you can add one more table and link the data with it.

Edit to answer changed question. 
You need to check does the value exist in the table before inserting new row.
If it exist do an update SQL query on that row. Otherwise insert new row.

Comment: This is the way to go. It's the only way to ensure data integrity. Also, take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php for retreiving the newly-inserted autoincrement id

Comment: Maybe incrementing isnt what I need? I am not 100% sure, I thought maybe that makes sense.. but in fact I am trying to create a new row if the id is new.. but overwrite it if the values change?

Ok so wouldnt I have to adjust some code to overwrite an existing ID... because by default wordpress does auto increment... how would I overwrite if its already been created..

Comment: If you want to generate a new, unique ID for a row, then yes this is what you want. You should add wordpress as a tag, and I haven't looked closely if you're using some builtin wordpress stuff or your own table. If you're still using wordpress's tables they may have functions to do what you want. Behind the scenes that's actually what they should be doing

Answer (score 0):

If you are running a standard Wordpress installation, the `wp_terms` table always has `auto_increment` as default for `term_id`, so you can just drop the static `$term_id`, the query now should be:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO $wpdb->terms (name, slug, term_group) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"; 

$wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare($query, $name, $slug, $term_group));
```

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:**

Your question now is quite different than the first one. First you have to do a `SELECT` query to see if the row with that `name` exist or not, something like:

```
$query = "SELECT FROM $wpdb->terms WHERE name=%s"; // remember to use prepare() after this
```

If that row doesn't exist then you can do the `INSERT` like above, if that row exists then you should do an `UPDATE` query:

```
$query = "UPDATE $wpdb->terms SET slug=%s, term_group=%s WHERE name=%s";
```

There is also [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) solution to replace above solution but I'm not so experienced with that.

Comment: Good point, you were right, similar to earlier It does generate its own id.. how does one overwrite an existing name?

Comment: this sounds like a good solution.. Im glad you took the time.. I gotta be somewhere, but Ill fiddle with it when I get back.. I bet it works.. thanks a million :)